# How to solve nonlinear equation with Python with three unknowns and hundreds of solutions?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to use python to find the values of three unknowns (x,y,z) in a nonlinear equation of the type:

```
g(x) * h(y) * k(z) = F
```

where F is a vector with hundreds of values.

I successfully used scipy.optimize.minimize where F only had 3 values, but that failed when the size of F was greater than 3.

How can I find (x,y,z) using all values in F? So far, the only usable approach is to use a grid search, but this quite inefficient (see # Find unknown x[0], x[1], x[2]). Is there a function in python that I can use to find x[0], x[1], x[2] instead of using the grid search?

Here the code:

```
import numpy as np

#  Inputs:
thetas = np.array([25.4,65,37,54.9,26,21.3,24.1,35.7,46.1,61.1,57.2,41.9,20.5,24,55.6,56.9,42.2,39.9,30.8,59,28.8])
thetav = np.array([28.7,5.4,22.6,14.4,23.5,25,12.8,31.2,15.3,9,7.4,24.4,29.7,15.3,15.5,26.8,8.8,16.6,25.1,18.5,12])
azs =    np.array([130.3,158,150.2,164.8,152.4,143.5,144.2,151.8,167.4,169.7,162.2,161.4,138.2,147.8,172.9,168.6,158.3,159.8,151.7,160.8,144.5])
azv =    np.array([55.9,312.8,38.6,160.4,324.2,314.5,236.3,86.1,313.3,2.1,247.6,260.4,118.9,199.9,277,103.1,150.5,339.2,35.6,14.7,24.9])
F =   np.array([0.61745,0.43462,0.60387,0.56595,0.48926,0.55615,0.54351,0.64069,0.54228,0.51716,0.39157,0.51831,0.7053,0.62769,0.21159,0.29964,0.52126,0.53656,0.575,0.40306,0.60471])

relphi = np.abs(azs-azv)

thetas = np.deg2rad(thetas)
thetav = np.deg2rad(thetav)
relphi = np.deg2rad(relphi)


#  Compute the trigonometric functions:
coss = np.abs (np.cos(thetas))
cosv = np.cos(thetav)
sins = np.sqrt(1.0 - coss * coss)
sinv = np.sqrt(1.0 - cosv * cosv)
cosp = -np.cos(relphi)
tans = sins / coss
tanv = sinv / cosv
csmllg = coss * cosv + sins * sinv * cosp
bigg = np.sqrt(tans * tans + tanv * tanv - 2.0 * tans * tanv * cosp)


# Function to solve
def fun(x):
    return x[0] * ((coss * cosv) ** (x[1] - 1.0)) * ((coss + cosv) ** (x[1] - 1.0)) * (1.0 - x[2] * x[2]) / ((1.0 + x[2] * x[2] + 2.0 * x[2] * csmllg) ** (1.5) + 1e-12) * (1.0 + ((1 - x[0]) / (1.0 + bigg))) - F


# Find unknown x[0], x[1], x[2]

n_bins=51
rho0_min=0.0
rho0_max=2.0
rho0_index=np.linspace(rho0_min, rho0_max, n_bins,retstep=True)
k_min=0.0
k_max=2.0
k_index=np.linspace(k_min, k_max, n_bins,retstep=True)
bigtet_min=-1.0
bigtet_max=1.0
bigtet_index=np.linspace(bigtet_min, bigtet_max, n_bins,retstep=True)
results=np.zeros((4,n_bins**3))
minima=np.ones(4)
RMSE_th = 0.001
index_while=0
current_RMSE=1.0
while current_RMSE > RMSE_th:
    index_results=0
    for rho0 in rho0_index[0]:
        for k in k_index[0]:
            for bigtet in bigtet_index[0]:
                results[:,index_results] = [rho0, k, bigtet, np.sqrt(np.sum((surf-func([rho0,k,bigtet]))**2) / surf.size)]
                index_results=index_results+1
    minima = results[:,np.argmin(results[3,:])]

    if (index_while > 10) or ((current_RMSE-minima[3]) < RMSE_th/100.0):
        break
    else:
        current_RMSE=minima[3]
        index_while=index_while+1
        rho0_min=minima[0]-2*rho0_index[1]
        rho0_max=minima[0]+2*rho0_index[1]
        rho0_index=np.linspace(rho0_min, rho0_max, 11,retstep=True)
        k_min=minima[1]-2*k_index[1]
        k_max=minima[1]+2*k_index[1]
        k_index=np.linspace(k_min, k_max, 11,retstep=True)
        bigtet_min=minima[2]-2*bigtet_index[1]
        bigtet_max=minima[2]+2*bigtet_index[1]
        bigtet_index=np.linspace(bigtet_min, bigtet_max, 11,retstep=True)


rho0= minima[0]
k= minima[1]
bigtet= minima[2]
print (rho0,k,bigtet,minima[3])

return (rho0,k,bigtet)
```

Comment: what is the output and what do you find unsatisfactory or it? And what are you using to do the minimization?

Comment: The output would be the triplet (x,y,z) -- or x[0], x[1], x[2] in terms of the python code.I am not clear about your suggestion below .. if I calculate the deviation, then what? So far, the only usable approach is a grid search across various values of x[0], x[1], x[2], and then picking the combination that minimize the RMSE. but this approach is quite inefficient as I can be stuck in local minima.

Comment: My point below is, you can not return an array, as you seem to be doing in func(x). Func(x) has to return a scalar, so instead of returning the deviations, as you are doing, I suggest returning the sum of all the squared deviations. So, I suggest returning the sum of the square of the whole array you are returning.

Comment: You will encounter the problem of local minima very often, especially for highly non-linear cases such as this one is.  You are trying for a very simple method to be very robust in a very complicated case, so you might need to think about other options for the minimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jblasco suggested, you can minimize the sum of squares. [scipy.leastsq()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html) is designed for such problems. For your example, the code would be:

```
import scipy.optimize as sopt

xx0 = np.array([0., 0., 0.])  # starting point
rslt = sopt.leastsq(fun, xx0, full_output=True)
print("The solution is {}".format(rslt[0]))
```

Look at the other entries of `rslts` for getting information on the quality of the solution. Keep in mind that the numerics can play tricks on you, especially when having exponents and hundreds of variables. If you have problems, check out the other [optimizers](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) from Scipy. Also giving explicit jacobians (as parameter of `leastsq()`) can help.

Answer (score 0):

Aha, I see. You are using scipy.optimize.minimize, which gets the function `fun(x)` as the function to minimize. But according to the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) minimize performs "Minimization of scalar function of one or more variables.". The clue here being *scalar*. You need to return a scalar. A classic method would be to minimize the sum of the square deviations:

```
deviations = x[0] * ((coss * cosv) ** (x[1] - 1.0)) * ((coss + cosv) ** (x[1] - 1.0)) * (1.0 - x[2] * x[2]) / ((1.0 + x[2] * x[2] + 2.0 * x[2] * csmllg) ** (1.5) + 1e-12) * (1.0 + ((1 - x[0]) / (1.0 + bigg))) - F
```

I strongly suggest you start chopping that expression to pieces, so that it's easier to understand. Then, the return of the function could be:

```
return sum( deviations ** 2)
```

Comment: I have added a few lines of code to find the unknown x[0], x[1], x[2] using grid search, but this is quite inefficient as I can be stuck in local minima.